# Form submission does not work with validationSchema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I want to create dynamic Form using Formik and Yup. On plus button press, new inputs should be added. However when I create validation schema, onSubmit method is not calling. When I delete validationSchema I can see the log in my console.

Here is my code:

```
interface Props {
    data?: string;
    onSubmit?: Function
}

interface IFormValues {
    people: {name: string, surname: string}[]
}


const FieldComponent = ({field, form: { touched, errors }}) => {
    const error = getIn(errors, field.name);
    const touch = getIn(touched, field.name);
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" name={field.name} onChange={field.onChange}/>
            {touch && error ? <p>{error}</p> : null}
        </div>
    )
}

const FieldArrayComponent = (arrayHelpers) => (
    <div>
        {arrayHelpers.form.values.people.map((person, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                <Field name={`people.${index}.name`} component={FieldComponent}/>
                <Field name={`people.${index}.surname`} component={FieldComponent}/>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({name: '', surname: ''})}>+</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}>-</button>
            </div>
        ))}
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
)

export const FormComponent: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
    const initialValues: IFormValues = {
        people: [{name: '', surname: ''}]
    }
    const schema = yup.object().shape({
        people: yup.array().of(
            yup.object().shape({
                name: yup.string().required('Required'),
                surname: yup.string().required('Required')
            })
        )
    })
    return (
        <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={values => {
            console.log(values);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}
        render={({ values }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray
                name="people"
                component={FieldArrayComponent}
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      />
    )
}
```

Can you take a look what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of passing `validationSchema` is to ensure that `onSubmit` doesn't get called if there are `errors`. I created a working example from your code. Have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-react-formik-validation-schema

You can see that `onSubmit` does get called if there are no errors. But if required fields are empty, `onSubmit` does not get called. That is the expected behavior.

However, if your intention was to debug in the case when errors are there (which is what I need to do quite often), checkout `render` method of `Formik` in which you can `console.log(values, errors)` to see the form errors or values instead of logging in `onSubmit`.

```js
render = {({ values, errors }) => {
  console.log(values, errors);
  return <Form>
    <FieldArray
      name="people"
      component={FieldArrayComponent}
    />
  </Form>
}}
```